# Can function call be used to send mail to multiple reciepients using smtp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

I've been trying to write a program which takes in names,mail id,subject and messages as a list and then sends them accordingly to each and everyone with a personalized mail.I have tried couple of things till date(like looping over smtp and then converting the messages and all to string )but it was not visually appealing and a bit complicated , so I re wrote the code but using a different approach(shown below) .Why am i getting the error?Also any suggestions/recommendation to the code is highly appreciated!

```
 import smtplib


user_email=input("Enter your email id:")
user_pwd=input("Enter your password:")

names_list=['abc','def']
mail_list=['abc@gmail.com','def@gmail.com']
subject_list=['Hi Where are you?','Hi how are your studies?']
messages_list=['Hi! where are you? been searching for you ,contact me asap','YOYOYOYOYOYOYOYOYOOOOO!!!']

def send_mail(mail,name,subject,message):
    try:
        server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.google.com',587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user_email,user_pwd)
        msg='Hi {}\nSubject:{}\n\n{}'.format(name,subject,message)
        server.sendmail(user_email,mail,msg)
        server.quit()
        print("Task Successfull!")
        print(msg)
    except:
        print("Unsuccessfull attempt :(")

for name,mail,subject,message in zip(names_list,mail_list,subject_list,messages_list):
    send_mail(mail,name,subject,message)
    msg1='{}\n{}\n{}\n{}'.format(name,mail,subject,message)
    print(msg1)
```

Output:

```
Enter your email id:arsaprsa@gmail.com
Enter your password:(hidden)
Unsuccessfull attempt :(
abc
abc@gmail.com
Hi Where are you?
Hi! where are you? been searching for you ,contact me asap
Unsuccessfull attempt :(
def
def@gmail.com
Hi how are your studies?
YOYOYOYOYOYOYOYOYOOOOO!!!
```

I have defined msg1 just to check whether my approach my right/wrong and to crosscheck.It is not of much significance.

(I've turned on the less secure apps on google in case you are wondering)

I know that in order to send mails to multiple recipients in quite complicated(like using msg["To"] and converting it to a string) but i was wondering if there was a way to complete this task with the help of functions.

Thank you for your time and helping me out!

Comment: Instead of just printing "unsuccessful attempt", it would be a lot more helpful if you caught the exception and printed the message.

Comment: Or even better: don't catch the exception at all (and specially not with a bare except clause - this should be forbidden).